How to define $\mathbb{R}^\frac{1}{2}$?
The Cayley-Dickson construction generates higher-dimensional hyper complex numbers from lower-dimensional ones, producing algebras of dimension $2^n$.
I want to generate an algebra of dimension $2^{-1}$, but there is no CD construction to go from higher to lower dimensions.
The question is: how can hypercomplex numbers with dimension $2^{-1}$ be defined?
Here’s what I tried:
Hypercomplex numbers with dimension $D$ are, geometrically, points in a $D$ dimensional space. According to the CD construction, a number $c \in \mathbb{R}$ (with dimension $D=1$) should be expressible as a pair of numbers $(c_0,c_1)$ from the $2^{-1}$ dimensional space.
So as  $2^{-1}$ dimensional space, I pick the set of real numbers, which when written in base $b$, have all zeros in odd-placed digits (counting the lowest significant entire digit as $0$ place).
This set of numbers creates a fractal, which, when scaled by $b^2$, forms $b$ copies of the original set. According to the Hausdorff dimension, they have dimension $D=\frac{\log(b)}{\log(b^2)}=\frac{1}{2}$.
I pick the binary base ($b=2$), because it is convenient to do numerical experiments.
Any number $n \in \mathbb{R}$ can be decomposed into its even and odd digits $n_0,n_1 \in \mathbb{R}^\frac{1}{2}$ with a binary $AND$ operation:
$n_0=n AND ...10101010101.0101...$
$n_1=n AND ...01010101010.1010...=(\frac{n}{2}) AND ...10101010101.0101...$
To recover the real number:
$n=(n_0,n_1)=n_0+2n_1$
The product rule in Cayley-Dickson construction is, for $ a \cdot b = c$, $(a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}),$
$$(a_0, a_1) \cdot (b_0, b_1) =(a_0 b_0−b_1 a_1^*, a_0^* b_1+b_0 a_1) = (c_0, c_1)$$
(wikipedia states this next version, but I use the former, as in most books)
$$\require{cancel}\cancel{(a_0, a_1) \cdot (b_0, b_1) = (a_0 b_0 - b_1^* a_1, b_1 a_0 + a_1 b_0^*) = (c_0, c_1)
}$$
then:
$c_0=a_0 b_0−b_1 a_1^*$
$c_1=a_0^* b_1+b_0 a_1$
The unknown concept is the definition of the conjugates $a_0^*, a_1^*$, so I numerically calculate the conjugates from the former equations:
$a_1^*=\frac{a_0 b_0−c_0}{b_1} $
$a_0^*=\frac{c_1-b_0 a_1}{b_1}$
But this produces inconsistent results, for example, when multiplying $a= [0,1,...,15]$ by $b=15$, the conjugate for $a_0=1$ may be $a_0^*=1,3,9,11...$

so this doesn't works. Can you give a hint, a different way to define $\mathbb{R}^\frac{1}{2}$, or fix my attempt?
The conjugate of $n_i$ should produce the modulus of $n_i$, by $|n|=n_i n_i^*$, but I have no clue about what is the meaning of length in $\mathbb{R}^\frac{1}{2}$. Does the Pythagorean theorem extend to $\mathbb{R}^\frac{1}{2}$? How?

How do you even define sums?

@Yaakov Baruch Is not clear to me. But $R$ should lose properties respect to $R^\frac{1}{2}$, and $n+n=2n$ doesn't stay in $R^\frac{1}{2}$, because it shifts bits, but maybe $R^\frac{1}{2}$, requires a pair of numbers in $R^\frac{1}{2}$, (same as complex numbers require a pair of reals). I'm lost.

It is very unclear to me what your goal even is. You also seem to be neglecting any issues arising from nonuniqueness of binary expansions.

I'm sympathetic to this sort of question, but I think in its present form it's not answerable. It's not clear what a successful answer would actually constitute: what sort of demands do you place on a candidate $\mathbb{R}^{1\over 2}$? At present I don't think this question is really appropriate for MO.

@Noah Schweber Notice the tag [soft-question]

Some versions of this question might be: does $\mathbb R$ have a square root as a topological space, as an abstract ring, as a topological ring? $\mathbb R$ as an abstract group is is course its own square root; I don't know about as a topological group. (Sorry, written before I saw the last few comments; they didn't load until after I posted.)

@LSpice In the context of Clifford algebra, this should lead to interpolation between integer dimensions, analogous to how real numbers interpolate between integers, but I don't know how to express it clearly, and it would mud the question even more.

@wepajakeg I am aware of that tag, but I think this question is too soft.

@wepajakeg This question of mine seems relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24891/the-root-of-a-line

@Max Muller There is some relationship in your question (but the pdf links are broken: 404). If you take the unit interval $[0,1)$, and take inside it $f_0$ as the fractal with dimension $D=\frac{1}{2}$, (similar to a cantor set) then you can generate any real number in the unit interval as the sum of some point in $f_0$ and $f_1=2f_0$, so the cartesian product $f_0 \wedge 2f_0$ is the unit line segment. I use the wedge symbol $\wedge$ from clifford algebra as part of the geometric product, and I call $f_0$ a fracvector.

@Max Muller But I cannot define the geometric product of fracvectors, because I don't know how to define the inner product, since I don't know how to measure or project in $\mathbb{R}^\frac{1}{2}$.

First of all, the space should be a fractal of dimension 1/2 and then you would have to start to try to define operations on it.

There are much, much more constructions of higher-dimensional hypercomplex algebras than Cayley-Dickson. Are you interested in generalizing exactly this construction or others as well, for istance, $\mathbb{R}^n$ (Cayley-Dickson is not $\mathbb{R}^n$)?

This question may be relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1466820/vector-spaces-with-fractional-dimension
